# pos_hint property not working properly in KivyMD MDBackdrop Python

Tags: python, kivy

So I am working on a file explorer user interface and I ran into a problem with the user interface. The user interface is basically divided into two parts. One of the parts contains a MDBackdrop. I wanted to position this Backdrop at the right side of the screen. So I added it into a BoxLayout and positioned it to the side of the screen as shown...

```
<MainScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        canvas:        
            Color:
                rgba: 0.05,0.05,0.05, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: root.pos
                size: root.size

            Color:
                rgba: 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1
            RoundedRectangle:                
                size:(root.width-10, root.height-10)
                pos:(5,5)
                radius: (30,30,30,30)

            Color:
                rgba: 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 1
            RoundedRectangle:                
                pos:(10,10)
                size:(400,root.height-20)
                radius: (30,30,30,30)
    BoxLayout:
        size:500,500
        size_hint_y : None
        size_hint_x : None
        pos_hint:{"right":1, "top": .95}

        MDBackdrop:
```

I also had to modify the source code of the Backdrop so that the actual back element and the toolbar at the top of the widget will be positioned correctly. The source code is at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD/master/kivymd/uix/backdrop.py

The line I changed is I added

```
pos:root.pos
```

after line 176 i.e. told the _frontLayer to follow the positioning of the root class(Backdrop)

I also want the toolbar to appear at the right of the screen rather than the left side of the screen so 
I changed(line 162 i.e.MDBackdropToolbar)

```
pos_hint: {'top': 1,}
```

to

```
pos_hint: {'top': 1, 'right':1}
```

the toolbar shift correctly but I get this extra blue rectangle which I just cannot figure out why and how to remove it...

[That weird rectangle that I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XRpc.png)

I have no idea why that rectangle keeps on showing up and how do I remove it? THANKS :)

Comment: Note that `root` refers to the root node of the enclosing `kv` rule. So I suspect that `root` in your case refers to `<MDBackdrop>`, not your `BoxLayout`.

Comment: ah yes...sorry that was mistake...I have changed the question so that it is correct....thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out the answer myself ;). Turns out nothing was wrong with MDBackdrop Widget it was actually the toolbar widget that was causing that weird rectangle. I edited the source code of the toolbar widget which can be found here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD/master/demos/kitchen_sink/studies/shrine/baseclass/toolbar.py

and I changed line 281 from

```
 (root.action_button.width - dp(6), self.height)) if root.type == "bottom" else self.pos
```

to

```
 (root.action_button.width - dp(6), self.height)) if root.type == "bottom" else self.size
```

i.e. I changed `self.pos` to `self.size`

and now that weird rectangle is gone

[The way I intended it to look like without that weird rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRvrS.png)